# Running local commands on OSX when command completes in ssh session

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, system-sounds

On my OS/X laptop, I can type "say done", and my mac says "done".

Locally, I'd just do:

```
do-something.sh && say done
```

And that lets me go screw around in separate windows/desktops until the script finishes.

But now I ssh from my mac to a remote Linux machine.  What I want is to be able to tell my mac to run "say done" when a specific command finishes.  Any good way to do that?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least let me know why?

Answer (score 3):

Hat tip to a coworker, A Golden, who came up with this immediately.  This is a cut-and-paste of their response, which works and completely nails this.

```
I picked "say-hi-locally" and set it up on my linux server as:
alias say-hi-locally="echo EMIT SAY HI"

Then, since I use ITerm2 as my local terminal, I set up a trigger in ITerm2 with the regexp "EMIT SAY HI" and told that to run the local command "say hi"

Now I can do:
do-something.sh; say-hi-locally

and when it finishes it will echo "EMIT SAY HI" which ITerm2 will then pick up and then my computer says "hi" to me! :-)
```

Comment: Wow this is so usefl..!!!

Answer (score 2):

On your Mac, start a TCP server that will send anything it receives to `say`:

```
mac $ while true; do nc -l 1234 | say; done
```

Then when you use SSH, use `-R` to forward port 1234 to your server:

```
mac $ ssh -R 1234:localhost:1234 linux
```

Now your Linux server should have a tunnel to the nc server on your Mac and can use `nc` to send text to it:

```
linux $ echo done | nc localhost 1234
```

Comment: If your Linux server doesn't have `nc` and you don't want to install it, then if you're using bash an alternative to the final command is `printf "done" >> /dev/tcp/localhost/1234`.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need an ssh server on your mac. Then you can do the following:

```
[you@mac]$ ssh linux
[you@linux]$ interactive_cmd; ssh mac say done
```

You login to your linux host, run the command, when it's done, the linux host ssh's back to your mac and runs the `say` command.

Comment: I want an interactive session, so this doesn't quite work.

Comment: It will work for interactive sessions. I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh linux do-something.sh && say done
```

looks like doing what you want. Implementing some communication between remote host and your mac does not seem feasible.

If you want to run more commands and you are worried about the latency, use `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist` options (a lot questions about that already answered).

Comment: That's not quite what I want, because it's an interactive terminal; I'm still working on the far end (and don't want a disconnect when the script finishes).

Comment: ^^ Check the second part of the answer. It does not disconnect connection, only session and initiation of new one is immediate. Or you can do it in separate terminal window/tab, while still having interactive session in the first one.

Comment: See my answer; this is actually feasible.